# Unable to set header via a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am attempting to send a token in the headers to an endpoint that validates token and simply returns a boolean.

Here is my code:

```
const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
  let token = localStorage.getItem("user");
  if (token === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("user", "");
    token = "";
  }

  console.log(token);

  const tokenRes = await axios.post(
    "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/user/tokenIsValid",
    null,
    {
      headers: {
        "x-auth-token": token,
      },
    }
  );

  console.log(tokenRes.data);
```

First log is to make sure im actually getting the token from localStorage.
The second log should console log true or false which is whats return from the post request.
I keep getting a 500 error when i run the post request. But if i pass in the actual token to headers instead of the token variable it works as intended.

Even when i get the error, when i look in the console and see the headers sent, i see that i did in fact send the token but still an error.

I dont understand why it wont accept the token variable.

I am a beginner so i apologize if i am not clear enough.

[image: Headers]

As you can see, i can log the token so i know im getting it. Also you can see that the token is being passed in to x-auth-token. But it comes back as invalid. If i pass the same token in directly all works well.

Here is my endpoint code:

```
router.post("/user/tokenIsValid", async (req, res) => {
try {
const token = req.header("x-auth-token");
if (!token) return res.json(false);

const verified = jwt.verify(token, config.get("jwtSecret"));
if (!verified) return res.json(false);

const user = await User.findById(verified.id);
if (!user) return res.json(false);

return res.json(true);
} catch (err) {
res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
}
});
```

Comment: Can you check the network console and see in headers if its (token) actually being passed when you call that function ?

Comment: In headers i see the token being passed in. The error response is "invalid token". However will work if i just pass in the token directly. I added a screen shot if it helps.

Comment: Can you console.log in your endpoint url to see if its the same format being passed what showing here in the screenshot.

Comment: I added the log in the endpoint and it logs the token and i get this:    Server running on port 5000
[0] MongoDB Connected...
[0] "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVmNWZjZjk1Yzg1YTNlNjMxMzNlZTU4NyIsImlhdCI6MTYwMDU2NzMzOCwiZXhwIjoxNjAwNTcwOTM4fQ.KMp0KXUbde6hoFUnJMDoF6BjPKAImJTT_iAVYpBW2C4"

Comment: The problem appears to be in the end point code the way this token is being sanitized  `Axios.post` is doing its job properly and sending the token successfully.

Comment: I apologize but i dont quite understand my course of action. Can i share my endpoint code with you?

Comment: If you can add the endpoint in your question yes that might help to see what goes on there. I am assuming it must be pretty simply token matching and returning true.

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: I can not reproduce any issue its working perfectly on my nodeJS enviroment. You can putting the token manually and see what happens like this => `const verified = jwt.verify(your_token_String, config.get("jwtSecret"));`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was when first issuing the jwt to the user. I was passing the token as JSON.stringify(token). I removed the JSON.stringify() and it worked.